# Express JS req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

req.body returns undefined.
Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const courses = [
    { id: 1, name: 'course1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'course2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'course3'},
];

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
    res.send(courses);
});


app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) =>{
    const course = {
        id: courses.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    courses.push(course)
    res.send(course)
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`))
```

Using postman to post an object, for example

```
{ 
    "name" : "newCourse"
}
```

will return only id, not returning both the expected id and name. Console.log(course.name) returns undefined.
This code is from a tutorial by Programming with Mosh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKd0Rpw7O48 Time: 33 min
I'm a beginner in node and express, any clue and explaination on why this doesn't work as it did in the tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line `app.use(express.urlencoded({}))` below `app.use(express.json())` line

Comment: I tried. Here is my console output: body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html):

> **req.body:**
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By
> default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing
> middleware such as body-parser and multer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that while using postman, i forgot to change the post input type from text to JSON. Once i set it to json, it works.